# Wronskian of a fundamental set of solutions

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems

Consider the system of equations:

$$\dot x_1=x_2$$
$$\dot x_2=-q(t)x_1-p(t)x_2$$

(Sorry I don't know how to do subscript notation for the 1's and 2's, an edit would be appreciated. Also the $x_1$ and $x_2$ should have dots above them, which I am not even sure of the meaning of...)

where $q(t)$ and $p(t)$ are continuous functions on all of $\Bbb R$. Find an expression for the Wronskian of a fundamental set of solutions.

So here's my (pathetic) attempt at a solution:

$$x_1=x_2\\
x_2=-q(t)x_1-p(t)x_2\\
x_2=-q(t)x_2-p(t)x_2\\
0=x_2+q(t)x_2+p(t)x_2\\
0=x_2(1+q(t)+p(t))$$

I don't really know how to attack this problem...

Comment: the dot is the derivative with respect to $t$.

Comment: @Jonny can you explain how you got that?

Comment: @mookid so its like dx1/dt and dx2/dt?

Comment: yes!${{{}}}{{{}}}$